# A column set as an Integer is a string at runtime

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class that uses SQLAlchemy to model a record in a database table, like so:

```
class PlanetModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'planetProbe'
    size = Column("SIZE", Integer)
    used_space = Column("USEDSPACE", Integer)
```

The columns are explicitly typed as integers. However, when I interact with the model, like so:

```
max_available_space = planet.size - planet.used_space
```

I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

Where should I start looking for what could be causing the values in my model to be typed as strings, even though they're clearly tagged as Integers in the code using sqlalchemy?

Comment: I have to admit, I know that this question isn't the best. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with Python and SQLAlchemy. I'm asking this question because I'm testing a program someone else wrote that I expected to Just Work. I was surprised to find a naked `TypeError` when I ran it. I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting that error in case it's an easy problem to fix before I talk to the people who gave me the program. If this is something I could have solved with some Googling, I'd appreciate being told which terms to search for - my research so far hasn't been helpful.

Comment: Even though the columns are declared `Integer`, the attributes can take on a string value through different mechanisms. One way is that the columns in the db are actually `varchar`; or, there's something wrong with your driver that makes it not interpret `int` values correctly (this may happen if you are not using a commonly-used setup); or, you've simply explicitly set them to `str`s, perhaps from user input, and haven't flushed the changes (this works when saving, because the db knows to do an automatic cast, but it doesn't work when you try to operate on them).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because those two values "planet.size" and "planet.used_space" are string type

```
a = "value1"
b = "value2"

print a - b
```

Output:

```
 print a - b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Just put a explicit casting on it as you are sure that these two columns will always contain integer values

```
max_available_space = int(planet.size) - int(planet.used_space)
```

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, I later need to save a value to one of these columns, and that doesn't work. Python gives me another TypeError saying I can't put an integer in a string variable.

Comment: You need to parse the integer back to the string and assign it to the column

Answer (score -3):

You need to first parse the string to integer.

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(String value);
```

Comment: This looks like Java code. My question is about Python.